# Mustache: Retrieve list/hash of tags from a template?

Tags: mustache

All the documentation and examples of Mustache I've seen show how to use a hash to populate a template. I'm interested in going the other direction. EG, if I have this:

```
Hello {{name}}
```

Can mustache generate this (pseudo-code):

```
tags = 'name'
```

I'm using the PHP flavor of Mustache, but I'm not too particular about the language. What I'm trying to do is build a system where people can create templates with Mustache tags, and another developer can quickly see what data the template will need. Is this something Mustache can do, or am I going to have to do some fun regex magic?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/) running on nodejs for example, and use the `scan` function:

```
var template = "{{foo}}{{#bar}}{{baz}}{{/bar}}{{#array}}{{.}}{{/array}}"'

var parsedTree = Hogan.scan(template, '{{ }}'​)​​​​;
```

What this returns is an array of objects. Each object entry has two keys that you want to look for: **n** represents the tag name, **tag** represents the tag type.
I don't think the tag types are clearly documented, but as a reference `_v` means plain text, `#` is a section start and `/` is section end.

Comment: this does not return name of tags, but tokens of the syntax. example output:

[
  { tag: '_v', n: 'foo', otag: '{{', ctag: '}}', i: 7 },
  { tag: '#', n: 'bar', otag: '{{', ctag: '}}', i: 15 }, .. ]

Answer (score 1):

`parse` method of [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) can be used in JavaScript to get the tree of tags used inside a given template:

```
const template = "{{foo}}{{#bar}}{{baz}}{{/bar}}{{#array}}{{.}}{{/array}}"
const tokens = Mustache.parse(template)
console.log(JSON.stringify(tokens, null, 4))
```

This will produce below:

```
[
    [
        "name",
        "foo",
        0,
        7
    ],
    [
        "#",
        "bar",
        7,

        15,
        [
            [
                "name",
                "baz",
                15,
                22
            ]
        ],
        22
    ],
    [
        "#",
        "array",
        30,
        40,
        [
            [
                "name",
                ".",
                40,
                45
            ]
        ],
        45
    ]
]
```

Comment: What's are the numbers?

Comment: numbers are start and end offsets of the tag

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Sanjay's answer, I think the following is what people are likely looking for, as it will recursively pull out all of the section tags on their own. If you instead, or in addition to, want it to return regular tags, not sections, check if current[0]==='name' to identify the other tags:

```
const template = "{{foo}}{{#bar}}{{baz}}{{/bar}}{{#array}}{{.}}{{/array}}"
const tokens = filterTokens(Mustache.parse(template))

function filterTokens(toParse, tokens=[]){
  for(let x=0; x<toParse.length; x++){
      const current = toParse[x];
      if(current[0] === '#' && !tokens.includes(current[1])){
          tokens.push(current[1]);
          if(toParse[4]){
              tokens.concat(filterTokens(current[4], tokens));
          }
      }
  }
  return tokens;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this question but I stumbled upon it when looking for a recommendation on how to do the same thing, in Ruby. Since I found a solution that's working well for me, I thought I would share:

Create a custom renderer, subclassed from Mustache, and track the requests for each partial or context there. You're going to want/need the normal rendering behavior anyway, since you'll want to catch contexts/partials referenced from other partials.

In Ruby, this is really easy to do -- hope it's still helpful for the PHP devs out there, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this one out myself in Ruby, since I couldn't find anything really useful through Google. Turns out it's simple:

`Mustache.templateify("{{name}} was {{location}}").tags`

This will return an array of tag names:

`["name", "location"]`