# Extract key names using Mustache Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, mustache

Does the Ruby Mustache API have a way to return the key names from a template?

Take, for example:

```
require 'mustache'
m = Mustache.new
m.template = "Hello {{first_name}} {{last_name}}"
```

I want to make an API call -- but I don't know what it is -- that returns the key names:

```
[:first_name, :last_name]
```

or something similar.

Comment: This related question has a PHP-related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355364/mustache-retrieve-list-hash-of-tags-from-a-template but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm also asking this question over on the [Mustache GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/issues/134).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way specifically to do that, but as a start you might consider the following:

```
>> pp Mustache::Template.new('Hello {{first_name}} {{person.last_name}}').tokens
[:multi,
 [:static, "Hello "],
 [:mustache, :etag, [:mustache, :fetch, ["first_name"]]],
 [:static, " "],
 [:mustache, :etag, [:mustache, :fetch, ["person", "last_name"]]]]
```

It should be fairly easy to write a traversal that extracted the relevant keys.

Answer (score 2):

Coincidentally, I've done this.

IIRC all I needed to do was implement a `tokens` method like so:

```
class Mustache::Template
  def tokens(src = @source)
    p = ::Mustache::Parser.new
    p.otag = PMustache::DEFAULT_MUSTACHE_OTAG
    p.ctag = PMustache::DEFAULT_MUSTACHE_CTAG
    p.compile(src)
  end
end
```

(You can ignore the `PMustache::DEFAULT_MUSTACHE_xTAG`s, they were to set the default delimiters.)

Feeding it a template like so:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'pmustache'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> f = Mustache.new
=> #<Mustache:0x007fce2192b520>
[3] pry(main)> f.template = "this is {{a}} test"
=> "this is {{a}} test"
```

allows access to the tokens:

```
[5] pry(main)> f.template.tokens
=> [:multi,
 [:static, "this is "],
 [:mustache, :etag, [:mustache, :fetch, ["a"]]],
 [:static, " test"]]
```

From there I think you basically want the `:mustache` tags:

```
[6] pry(main)> p_toks = lambda { |tok| (tok.instance_of? Array) && (tok[0] == :mustache) }      
=> #<Proc:0x007fce228b0b08@(pry):6 (lambda)>
[7] pry(main)> f.template.tokens.find_all(&p_toks)      
=> [[:mustache, :etag, [:mustache, :fetch, ["a"]]]]
```

I had some other hackery in there as well; we had dot-separated template vars and presented them on a user interface (probably more or less what you're doing) so we could group them by functionality, load them from a JSON object, blah blah blah.

You may only want certain token types; pulling the tokens out of the compiled template is straight-forward, so once you throw some templates at it, you'll see what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Have you considered submitting a pull request to {?

Comment: @DavidJames Sort of, except that IMO on its own it's likely not super-useful. I did almost fork it in a fit of anger during this process, though.

Comment: According to a reply at https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/issues/134, it looks like a tokens method already exists.

Comment: @DavidJames I'd have to revisit it all to know why I did what I did; it was some time ago. Thanks for the followup.

Comment: @DavidJames I think I did that to set the custom delimiters; no other reason--sorry; I conflated two different things in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Mustache::Template#tags`](https://github.com/mustache/mustache/blob/02050f4d06e2d6fcd43a9ded6d197ad235ef96b4/lib/mustache/template.rb#L61)

```
>> Mustache::Template.new('Hello {{first_name} {{last_name}}').tags
[
    [0] "first_name",
    [1] "last_name"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't see this as being supported by the API. I've searched the source code for version 0.99.4 of mustache. The closest I've found is the `has_key?` and `fetch` methods in [context.rb](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/blob/master/lib/mustache/context.rb). After reading these methods, it would appear that the keys are not cached.

Answer (score 0):

Some like this looks to work fine when you have only simple key names:

```
tokens = Mustache::Template.new('Hello {{first_name}} {{person.last_name}}').tokens
pp tokens.find_all{|token| token.is_a?(Array) && token[0] == :mustache }.map{|token| token[2][2]}
```

For your exact desire, you might need something like:

```
pp tokens.find_all{|token| token.is_a?(Array) && token[0] == :mustache }.map{|token| token[2][2].last.to_sym}.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context in the class. For instance...

```
s = Simple.new
s[:first_name] = "Steve"
s[:last_name] = "Rogers"
puts s.full_name

class Simple < Mustache
  def full_name
    "#{context[:first_name]} #{context[:last_name]}"
  end
end
```

will return `Steve Rogers`.